# How to create several pandas frames with a for loop in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to generate 11 models of Decision Tree, for that, one of the steps is to assigns the y values for each one.

Since I have 11 y variables, I would like to assign each one automatically.

The df['P1 d'] is a DataFrame column with the 'dummies' variables.

```
X2 = df[['1_y', '2_y', '3_y', '4_y', '5_y', '6_y', '7_y', '8_y','9_y', '10_y','11_y', '12_y', '13_y', '14_y']]
for t in range(1,12):
    'y.{}'.format(t) = df[['P{} d'.format(t)]]
```

The error message is:

```
 File "<ipython-input-83-017c94c44d4b>", line 3
'y.{}'.format(t) = df[['P{} d'.format(t)]]
^
```

SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

I know it might be something very simple, but I have not been able to think on anything to overcome this setback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`'y.{}'.format(t)` will return a string, not a variable. You can't assign a DataFrame to a string.

What you could do is:

- Create a dict with your y{} keys
- Put each dataframe to a key

```py
my_dict = {}
for t in range(1,12):
    key = 'y.{}'.format(t)
    my_dict[key] = df[['P{} d'.format(t)]]
```

You can use a dict comprehension if needed